# PHP forward slash match

Tags: php, regex

How I can check if some string contains forward slash in PHP?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check for occurences with [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
if (strpos($string, '/') !== FALSE) // Found
```

> Returns the position as an integer. If needle is not found, strpos() will return boolean FALSE.

This is faster than a regular expression, and most other methods, because it stops checking at the first occurrence.

Answer (score 4):

It is very simple:

```
preg_match ('~/~', $string);
```

Comment: From the manual: *Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use strpos() or strstr() instead as they will be faster.*

Comment: Using `preg_match` has the advantage of being easier to understand than the weird `strpos!==false` code. As long as your critical path doesn't include checking a million strings whether they contain a string, I'm pretty sure `preg_match` is fine. It's also easier to refactor if eg. you decide you only want to match trailing slashes...